# How to store/export coins from bitcoind to papper wallet 'cold storage'

Tags: bitcoind, coldstorage

I have bitcoind 0.9.1 installed on my VPS debian server. I would like to store my coins via "cold storage", on paper wallets.

I read some articles over internet, but i don't know which one is usable/achievable in this case.

Could someone tell me some ideas how can i achieving cold storage via bitcoind.

Comment: With that do you need help? Creating a paper wallet, sending bitcoins, or whether its possible or not?

Comment: Well, i would like to know how can i transfer coins from my bitcoind's wallet into a papper wallet.If its possibel, how can i do that, i think i need a "step by step tutorial".

Comment: You can create a paper wallet (from a link from [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet#Producing_safe_paper_wallets) for example) and then send the bitcoin to the address associated to that wallet. Then it is in the so-called *cold storage*. The paper does not need to know there are bitcoins on it, you just want to have the private key (which is printed on it) associated to the address you have sent you BTC to, whenever you want to access the BTC again

Comment: The idea is that you have a private key on the paper wallet, which is the ONLY (so dont loose it ;) ) option to access that specific wallet. Whatever ends up in that wallet is yours, whenever you send it (so before or after printing, but you have to create the address/key before sending of course)

Comment: @Mathias711 Those comments together would make a nice answer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. But I needed to ask where he need help with. And then I just answered in the comments instead of the answer box. I will copy/paste it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a paper wallet (from a link from [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet#Producing_safe_paper_wallets) for example) and then send the bitcoin to the address associated to that wallet. Then it is in the so-called cold storage. The paper does not need to know there are bitcoins on it, you just want to have the private key (which is printed on it) associated to the address you have sent you BTC to, whenever you want to access the BTC again

The idea is that you have a private key on the paper wallet, which is the ONLY (so dont loose it ;) ) option to access that specific wallet. Whatever ends up in that wallet is yours, whenever you send it (so before or after printing, but you have to create the address/key before sending of course)